# error casting JList to DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have implemented a button that will simply delete a "contact" in the JList contactList. What the program is supposed to do is if the button deletes "Broadcast", which is the first element in contactList, will return an error by outputting a display message. Otherwise, it is supposed to simply remove the contact from the contact list.

My question is how do I delete the contact from the JList using DefaultListModel correctly? I saw that DefaultListModel needs to be used because remove function isn't in JList nor ListModel.

What the example contact list of size 4 may look like:

```
[Broadcast]
[Andro]
[Denis]
[Micheal]
...
```

This is the error:

```
[java] Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$4 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel
... //rest of error
```

Code:

```
private JList<String> listContacts;

//constructor:
listContacts = new JList<String>(controller.getContacts());
//gets contact list from controller class which gets contact list from client class.
listContacts.setModel(new DefaultListModel());

JButton deleteUser = new JButton("Delete User");
menuPanel.add(deleteUser,BorderLayout.EAST);
deleteUser.addActionListener(new MyButtonListener5());

class MyButtonListener5 implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    DefaultListModel<String> list = (DefaultListModel)(listContacts.getModel());
    String contact = listContacts.getSelectedValue();
    int j = -1;
    for(int i = list.getSize()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(list.getElementAt(i).equals("Broadcast")) {
            controller.displayMsg("[ERROR] You cannot delete broadcast\n");
        }
        else if(list.getElementAt(i).equals(contact)){
            j = i;
        }
    }
    if(j != -1){
        list.remove(j); 
    }
}
```

Comment: .. what is your question? Do you understand what the compiler message means? Please research things before writing a post here (& when you get to that stage - form a *specific* question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(DefaultListModel)list.remove(j);
```

list.remove() returns the item that was removed from the list, which in your case is a String. Why are you casting it to a DefaultListModel?

or did you really mean

```
((DefaultListModel<String>)list).remove(j);
```

which casts "list" to a DefaultListModel, and then calls that model's remove() method. But "list" is already declared as a DefaultListModel, so the cast is superfluous.
Just get rid of the cast.

Comment: I got rid of the cast at the line you mentioned and the code still produces the error.